# В чем разница между x+=y и x=x+y?

Tags: python

Есть ли разница между

```py
x += y
```

и

```py
x = x + y
```

для встроенных типов? Если не в семантике, то в быстродействии?

Comment: По идее разницы нет, это просто "синтаксический сахар", т.е. первый вариант - это другая, более короткая форма записи того же самого.

Comment: Хм, разница всё же есть некоторая и с точки зрения самого питона: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376509/when-is-i-x-different-from-i-i-x-in-python

Comment: @CrazyElf, это нельзя считать "синтаксическим сахаром". Для списков разная семантика.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

***NB** Это всё проверялось для CPython 3.10. В других интерпретаторах/компиляторах результат может быть другим (другим по времени, но тем же по результату!).*

Разница в одной инструкции: `INPLACE_ADD` или `BINARY_ADD`.

> ```
> def f():                          def g():
>     x = 10                            x = 10
>     x += 1                            x = x + 1
>
>  0 LOAD_CONST     1 (10)          0 LOAD_CONST     1 (10)
>  2 STORE_FAST     0 (x)           2 STORE_FAST     0 (x)
>
>  4 LOAD_FAST      0 (x)           4 LOAD_FAST      0 (x)
>  6 LOAD_CONST     2 (1)           6 LOAD_CONST     2 (1)
>  8 INPLACE_ADD                    8 BINARY_ADD
> 10 STORE_FAST     0 (x)          10 STORE_FAST     0 (x)
> 12 LOAD_CONST     0 (None)       12 LOAD_CONST     0 (None)
> 14 RETURN_VALUE                  14 RETURN_VALUE
> ```

### Числа, строки и кортежи

Для целых и вещественных чисел слот `nb_inplace_add` не заполнен ([например для целых](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/longobject.c#L6214)). Это значит что обе инструкции `INPLACE_ADD` и `BINARY_ADD` выполняют один и тот же код из слота `nb_add`. Результат работы и время одинаковы и в теории и на практике.

Для строк и кортежей ситуация такая же. Инструкции исполняют один и тот же код - результат одинаковый и время одинаковое.

### Списки

Тут хитрее: отличается и результат и время. `+=` выигрывает, так как не изготавливает новый список - конкатенацию аргументов, а сразу добавляет элементы правого списка в левый. Примеры ниже немного нечестные по отношению к `+=` - список `n` растёт. Тем не менее `+=` лидирует с огромным отрывом.

***NB** **Разная семантика!** `f` и `g` по разному работают со списком `n`. `f` его меняет, `g` оставляет неизменным.*

В случае списков последняя инструкция `STORE_FAST` не нужна - это фактически самоприсваивание. Но код не знает про типы и делает лишнюю операцию. Мелочь, показывающая почему компиляторы любят строгую типизацию.

Очень быстро:

```
n = [0] * 1000
m = [1]


def f():
    x = n
    x += m


for _ in range(1_000_000):
    f()
```

> ```
> $ time python f.py
>
> real  0m0.202s
> user  0m0.200s
> sys   0m0.000s
> ```

Очень медленно:

```
n = [0] * 1000
m = [1]


def g():
    x = n
    x = x + m


for _ in range(1_000_000):
    g()
```

> ```
> $ time python g.py
>
> real  0m4.403s
> user  0m4.296s
> sys   0m0.004s
> ```

Comment: Логичный вопрос так а в чём разница между этими инструкциями? Может одна быть быстрее другой? Могут они иметь разные последствия?

Comment: Вообще думаю это сильно зависит от конкретного интерпретатора. В данном случае я бы на его месте вообще `INC` какой применил в качестве оптимизации )

Comment: можно просто посмотреть наличие `__iadd__` у класса. У `int` нету, у `list` есть. не изменяемые типы не реализуют такие методы (`str`, `int`, `float`), а изменяемые реализуют

Comment: интерпретатору ведь нужно проверить наличие `nb_inplace_add`? Если это так, то различие в скорости есть, но она ничтожно мала

Answer (score 8):

можно заметить разницу при работе со списками:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5, 6]

z = x
x = x + y
x[0] = 10

print(z)
```

и

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5, 6]

z = x
x += y
x[0] = 10

print(z)
```

вывод будет разный. Это происходит потому что первый вариант создаёт новый список, а второй вариант добавляет элементы в конец.

когда происходит сложение то вызывается `__add__`, который возвращает новый объект. А когда `+=` вызывается `__iadd__`, который меняет текущий объект. Если же `__iadd__` отсутствует то результат будет абсолютно таким же как при обычном сложение.